# Counting and ordering

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> describe taps;
+------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field      | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| tag        | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| station    | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| time_Stamp | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
+------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

How do I get the number of staions visited by each tag and sort by the most visits - where we only count one visit to each staion, even if there were several?

Random data:

```
mysql> select * from taps;
+-----+---------+---------------------+
| tag | station | time_Stamp          |
+-----+---------+---------------------+
|  50 |      12 | 2016-05-10 20:02:41 |
|  33 |       7 | 2016-05-10 20:02:42 |
|  34 |      13 | 2016-05-10 20:02:42 |
|  31 |       3 | 2016-05-10 20:02:42 |
|   9 |      10 | 2016-05-10 20:02:42 |
|   2 |      11 | 2016-05-10 20:02:42 |
|  33 |      13 | 2016-05-10 20:02:42 |
|  46 |      12 | 2016-05-10 20:02:42 |
|  45 |       1 | 2016-05-10 20:02:42 |
|  34 |       7 | 2016-05-10 20:02:42 |
|   4 |      10 | 2016-05-10 20:08:18 |
|  17 |       5 | 2016-05-10 20:08:19 |
|  46 |       7 | 2016-05-10 20:08:19 |
|  16 |       5 | 2016-05-10 20:08:19 |
|  33 |       3 | 2016-05-10 20:08:19 |
|  31 |       4 | 2016-05-10 20:08:19 |
|   1 |      13 | 2016-05-10 20:08:19 |
|  35 |       2 | 2016-05-10 20:08:19 |
|   9 |      12 | 2016-05-10 20:08:19 |
|  26 |       7 | 2016-05-10 20:08:19 |
+-----+---------+---------------------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: would you mind add some sample data

Comment: Hello transit data analyst! Can you provide a reproducible dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT` funtion and `GROUP BY` to find the number of visits for each `tag`.

And use `ORDER BY` clause to sort the result in descending of the number of visits.

**Query**

```
SELECT tag, COUNT(DISTINCT station) AS `no of visits`
FROM taps
GROUP BY tag
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT station) DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, you just need to use `count` with `distinct`:

```
select tag, count(distinct station) cnt
from taps
group by tag
order by 2 desc
```