# Counting and ordering and joining

Tags: mysql

My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146951/counting-and-ordering) gave me the answer that I could take

```
mysql> describe taps;
+------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field      | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| tag        | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| station    | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| time_Stamp | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
+------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and use the query

```
SELECT tag
     , COUNT(DISTINCT station) as `visit_count` 
  FROM taps 
 GROUP 
    BY tag 
 ORDER 
    BY COUNT(DISTINCT station) DESC
```

to get the visitors ordered by the number of stations they have visited.

Now I want to add

```
mysql> describe visitors;
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| tag_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| name   | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| email  | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| phone  | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And, instead of getting the visitors `tag_id`, I want to get his `name`, `email` and `phone`. I know that it involves a`JOIN`, but just can't figure it out :-(

---

[Update] Just to be clear, I want to output an HTML table, ordered by whoever visited the most stations, showing name, email & phone

Comment: You cannot get the visitors, if you are grouping by stations.

Comment: Group by visitors instead.

Comment: can you tell me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tag
     ,v.email, COUNT(DISTINCT station) as `visit_count` 
  FROM taps as t JOIN visitors as v ON t.tag = v.tag_id
 GROUP 
    BY v.email
 ORDER 
    BY COUNT(DISTINCT station) DESC
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are grouping by email & what happened to phone? Sorry. In any case, this returned `Empty set`

Comment: You can use email or phone, whichever is unique.  Try without the group by clause, are you getting any output ?

Comment: The only thing that is unique is the `tag_Id`, so I JOIN on that. I need to GROUP because I want to get the count, not each individual visit.

Comment: The number of visits to each station. I will update the question, to make it clearer

Comment: @Mawg, the code only will give an empty set if your `tag_id` doesn't match your `tag` (or you made some mistake in your php code). What are your keys in `taps`? Can you verify that your data is as we think: if a Person A visits Station B and Station C, and he has the entry `Tag_id = 1`, `name =  Person A` in the table `visitors`. Does that Person now has two entries in in the table `taps`, one with `tag = 1` and `Station = Station B` and one with `tag = 1` and `Station = Station B`. Test the following: What is the result of: `select count(*) from taps t join visitors v on t.tag = v.tag_id`?

Comment: Yes, itr is  as you say. That person will have twpo entries in the `taps` table.

Comment: @Magw, I assumed there will be two entries, the important question is if they have the same id. Can you please do: `select count(*) from taps t join visitors v on t.tag = v.tag_id`. There might be something wrong with your data.